# Qt Creator don't have "Qt Gui Application" to choose when creating new project

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

After installing Qt Creator, from http://qt-project.org/downloads - "Qt Creator 2.5.2 for Windows (31 MB)" when I choose File->New File [...]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhJ30.png

It's probably stupid question, but don't now why it is so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install the Qt SDK instead. When you download Qt Creator, all you get is the IDE, you don't actually get Qt or a compiler. The SDK is much easier.

Edit: The SDK can be found [here](http://qt-project.org/downloads), at least at the time of writing, and it seems that from Qt 5 and onwards, the default download includes both Qt and Qt Creator.

Comment: Thanks! Downloading it right now. I've already seen this 'Qt SDK' on YT videos but thought Qt creator is the same.